# Is a request to dismiss a motion the same as requesting denial of the motion?

Tags: pleadings

Given the statement:

> Defendant respectfully move this Honorable Court to **deny** and
> **dismiss** Plaintiffs motion dated 1/1/20.

If the goal is to ask the ajudicating authority to not perform opposing counsel's request, is there any difference if the word **deny** is removed?

> Defendant respectfully move this Honorable Court to **dismiss**
> Plaintiffs motion dated 1/1/20

IANAL and trying to get a sense of the nuance of the pleading language.

Answer (score 3):

A court would "dismiss" an action, a claim, or a defendant, but I don't know of any American court that would "dismiss" a motion.

Instead, a motion would be "denied," or perhaps "overruled."

If I saw this language in a motion, I would assume it was just a lawyer doing the stereotypical redundance thing.